# jquery-datatable: incorrect "Showing <range> of <total> entries" message is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am working on developing an ASP.NET web page where data will be displayed in a jquery Datatable. I am able to display the data but, **the issue I am facing is, the information "Showing  of  entries" is displaying an incorrect value.**

**Fiddler:** https://jsfiddle.net/8f63kmeo/9/

**HTML:**

```
    <table id="CustomFilterOnTop" class="display nowrap" width="100%"></table>
```

**JS**

```
var Report4Component = (function () {
    function Report4Component() {
        //contorls
        this.customFilterOnTopControl = "CustomFilterOnTop"; //table id
        //data table object
        this.customFilterOnTopGrid = null;
        //variables
        this.result = null;
    }
    Report4Component.prototype.ShowGrid = function () {
        var instance = this;
        //add footer
        $('#' + instance.customFilterOnTopControl)
            .append('<tfoot><tr><th colspan="2" class="total-text">Total</th><th class="total-value"></th></tr></tfoot>');
        //create the datatable object
        instance.customFilterOnTopGrid = $('#' + instance.customFilterOnTopControl).DataTable({
            columns: [
                { data: "Description", title: "Desc" },
                { data: "Status", title: "Status" },
                { data: "Count", title: "Count" }
            ],
            "paging": true,
            scrollCollapse: true,
            "scrollX": true,
            scrollY: "300px",
            deferRender: true,
            scroller: true,
            dom: '<"top"Bf<"clear">>rt <"bottom"<"Notes">i<"clear">>',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Load All',
                    action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                        instance.ShowData(10000);
                    }
                }
            ],
            initComplete: function (settings) {
                var api = this.api(settings);
                //now, add a second row in header which will hold controls for filtering. 
                $(api.table().header()).append('<tr role="row" id="FilterRow">' +
                    '<th>Desc</th>' +
                    '<th>Status</th>' +
                    '<th>Count</th>' +
                    '</tr>');
                //add input controls for filtering
                $('#FilterRow th', api.table().header()).each(function () {
                    var title = $('#' + instance.customFilterOnTopControl + ' thead th').eq($(this).index()).text();
                    $(this).html('<input type="text" onclick="return false" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" class="form-control" />');
                });
                //todo: refactor this code. this is for displaying the scrollbar below the tfoot instead of tbody
                //when multiple tables are present, use tablename.find to get the specific class object
                //this code is not tested with other options
                $('.dataTables_scrollBody').css({
                    'overflow-x': 'hidden',
                    'border': '0'
                });
                $('.dataTables_scrollFoot').css('overflow', 'auto');
                $('.dataTables_scrollFoot').on('scroll', function () {
                    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollLeft($(this).scrollLeft());
                });
            },
            footerCallback: function (tfoot, data, start, end, display) {
                var api = this.api();
                if (instance.result == null || instance.result.Total == undefined) {
                    return;
                }
                $(api.column(2).footer()).html(instance.result.Total);
            }
        });
        $("div.Notes").html('<div class="alert alert-warning">This is a notes section part of the table dom.</div>');
    };
    Report4Component.prototype.BindEvents = function () {
        var instance = this;
        $("#FilterRow th input").on('keyup change', function () {
            instance.customFilterOnTopGrid
                .column($(this).parent().index() + ':visible')
                .search("^" + $(this).val(), true, false, true) //uses regular expression and checks only for starts with
                .draw();
        });
    };
    Report4Component.prototype.ShowData = function (limit) {
        if (limit === void 0) { limit = 100; }
        var instance = this;
        instance.customFilterOnTopGrid.clear(); //latest api function
        instance.result = instance.GetData(limit);
        instance.customFilterOnTopGrid.rows.add(instance.result.RecordList);
        instance.customFilterOnTopGrid.draw();
    };
    Report4Component.prototype.GetData = function (limit) {
        //structure of the response from controller method
        var resultObj = {};
        resultObj.Total = 0;
        resultObj.RecordList = [];
        for (var i = 1; i <= limit; i++) {
            resultObj.Total += i;
            var record = {};
            record.Description = "This is a test description of record " + i;
            record.Status = ["A", "B", "C", "D"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)] + 'name text ' + i;
            record.Count = i;
            resultObj.RecordList.push(record);
        }
        return resultObj;
    };
    return Report4Component;
}());
$(function () {
    var report4Component = new Report4Component();
    report4Component.ShowGrid();
    report4Component.BindEvents();
    report4Component.ShowData();
});
function StopPropagation(evt) {
    if (evt.stopPropagation !== undefined) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }
    else {
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
    }
}
```

**Issue:**

In the snapshot below, you can see that there are 8 records displayed in the grid but, the count is showing as 1 to 1 of 100. It should be 1 to 8 of 100.

[image]

**Observation:**

If you resize the page, the counts seems to appear correctly. I don't want to trigger window resize event after every draw. Is there any api available to handle this issue?

**Expectation:**

How should I fix this issue? Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you even want pagination information? It looks like you're using scrolling, not paging. My initial hunch is that you get incorrect information because of the scrolling. It's not going to dynamically update based on the number of visible rows.

Comment: The "showing..." message will indicate the current position of the user when they are scrolling and viewing the data. See this example: https://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/examples/initialisation/simple.html

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize scroller could do that. An interesting observation is that when I resize the live example in the fiddle, the numbers become correct.

Comment: Yes, I just noticed too. Updated my question with the observation.

Answer (score 2):

With some fiddling (heh) with the JSFiddle, I think I've detected the reason for this issue.

**Summary of Issue:**

There's some issue whereby the scroller is unaware that the addition of all your rows (using `rows.add()` instead of initializing the table with the rows) has increased the physical dimensions of the table, and so believes that the initial 0 row table is the current size. This causes it to calculate the number of visible rows incorrectly. `draw()` won't help because it doesn't recreate the table, just the data, which is correct. The internal dimensions of the table are being given to scroller incorrectly. This may not be fixable with the way you've decided to load data without completely destroying and re-creating the table.

**Workaround Solution:**

Since you create and load your table/events before loading the data, somehow the scroller isn't aware that the Y dimension of the table has changed (the table is created with 0 rows, so it thinks there isn't room for more than 1). I'm not really exactly sure what you should do to update the scroller, but I found a workaround solution. If you don't like this workaround, you'll have to examine the possibility of loading your data during the construction of the table.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnuutbzb/) where all I've done is change your HTML table by adding dummy rows:

```
<table id="CustomFilterOnTop" class="display nowrap" width="100%">
<tr><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td></tr>
<tr><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td></tr>
<tr><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td></tr>
<tr><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td></tr>
<tr><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td></tr>
<tr><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td></tr>
<tr><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td></tr>
<tr><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td></tr>
<tr><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td><td>asdf</td></tr>
</table>
```

This tricks the scroller into believing that there is room for 9 rows, which is how many you'll initially have. You're basically padding the initial table out to your `300px` definition.

And note that while the table appears to operate the exact same, it will now display the correct paging information. Note that these rows are destroyed when you initialize and load your table, so they're just a filler so that scroller knows to expect more rows.

This is very 'hack-y', but hopefully it at least provides some insight into where you should look next, or a temporary workaround.

A better solution would be to load the data into the table when it is initialized, which is the standard way of doing it anyways.

Comment: thanks for your response. But, I don't want to add dummy rows.I am guessing that there should be some api / method in datatable which will help us in fixing this issue...

Comment: The issue isn't that datatables is doing something wrong that you can fix, it's that your custom way of inserting data (after the table is created) to the table is non-standard (not necessarily wrong), which is causing scroller to work incorrectly. I'm surprised re-drawing the table doesn't fix it, but you may be stuck with this if you don't change your way of loading the data to the table, use dummy rows, or somehow reload the table after data is loaded.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh I added a summary which hopefully helps you to at least diagnose the issue. I'd recommend posting on the DataTables forums about this, as it seems to be a (minor) bug in the DataTables code, even if there is a workaound.